# error attempting to acquire connection factory "jms/remoteconnectionfactory" subsystem=messaging-activemq on jboss

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm using a code I found :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   Context namingContext = null; 
   try { 
      String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME); 
      String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD); 

      // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup 
      final Properties env = new Properties(); 
      env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY); 
      env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL)); 
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName); 
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

      namingContext = new InitialContext(env); // Perform the JNDI lookups String 
      connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY); 
      log.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \\"" + connectionFactoryString + "\\""); 
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString); 
      log.info("Found connection factory \\"" + connectionFactoryString + "\\" in JNDI");
```

Comment: What software are you using? What error are you seeing? What do you expect/want to see?

Comment: org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final-redhat-1
juil. 27, 2023 5:41:48 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Attempting to acquire connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
juil. 27, 2023 5:41:53 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
SEVERE: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [remote://localhost:8080 (Operation failed with status WAITING after 5000 MILLISECONDS)]

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS   i'm using jboss EAP7 and I activated activemq subsystem . I'm able to create queues and topics

Comment: You need to add these details **to your question** instead of in the comments. Please be sure to add proper formatting so things like logs and code are easy to identify and read.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution I have to run jboss using standalone-full.xml config and use only the jboss client jar in bin directory in jboss .